# How to match until get specific pattern in Regex

Tags: regex

I have a scenario where i want to match specific word and then match everything until i get another pattern. For example

**ABC=145865865**

Then anything comes in ways

and then

**Date=11/11/2001**

I have tried (.*?) but it only match that specific line in my scenario i have multiple lines of data in between.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest guess to what I think you're looking for:

`ABC=(\d+)[\s\S]*?Date=(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})`

This uses `[\s\S]` which means "either a whitespace character or not a whitespace character", which is equivalent to "any character". The `.` can also be set to match any character, but I tend to prefer `[\s\S]` because it does just that without having to set flags. You haven't specified the language you are using so I can't tell you how to set such a flag anyway (it's `re.DOTALL` in Python).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple lines? If you mean you have newline characters (\n) in between then you need to set the DOTALL flag, as follows:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(<your-regex-here>, Pattern.DOTALL)
```

The above will match new line characters between the two strings.